# Is it better to set social media sharer in entry-footer.php or comments.php in Wordpress blog?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-sharer, social-media

I'm now deciding where should I put social media sharers. Currently, I'm now putting sharers code in `entry-footer.php`. But is it more semantic to put sharers in `entry-footer.php`, in the bottom of every post, or `comments.php`, being together with comment box in Wordpress?

Also, since the `entry-footer.php` is the default structure only for *single post*, is it reasonable to ask `page.php` to load `entry-footer.php`, too? Or should I just rewrite a block of sharer codes inside `page.php`? How about loading `comments.php` with sharer codes inside?

Comment: This isn't really a programming-issue, more of a structural-issue, which in turn is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Better in terms of what? Performance? Visibility? UI? Something else?

Comment: @ScallioXTX to make it more logical for future reviewers

Answer (score 1):

I use and suggest you keep it in entry-footer.php as people are sharing your current single Entry and not its comments on the social media.

Comment: Thank for the idea. :)